# Javascript idiosyncrasy: valueOf clarification in if statement?

Tags: javascript

The problem is solve this magic condition:

```js
var magic = ???;

if(magic < 1 && magic > 1){
    console.log('Inside')
}

//magic solution 1 - WORKS

var magic = (function(){ 
    var val = -2; 

    return { 
        valueOf(){ 
            return val = val + 2; 
        } 
    } 
})();

// magic solution 2 - DOESN'T WORK

var magic = { 
    val: -2, 
    valueOf: function(){ 
        return this.val + 2; 
    } 
};
```

Can someone clarify how this snippet works? I thought both are same.

Comment: Both those examples work just fine, but they aren't even remotely the same, so if the second one doesn't work, you're probably using it incorrectly, but as you're not really showing us how you intend to use it, or even ask a proper question, it's hard to answer ?

Comment: @adeneo for second magic object it doesn't satisfy the if condition .. so the question is why it doesn't ?

Answer (score 1):

Both of these snippets use 'kinda-magic' side of JavaScript: when object is used in expression that makes sense for primitives only (such as comparison with number), it is cast to primitive by [ToPrimitive()](https://es5.github.io/#x9.1) operation - either with `valueOf()` or `toString()` method of an object itself, depending on the expression particularities (more details [here](https://es5.github.io/#x8.12.8)).

In `(magic < 1 && magic > 1)` expression such cast happens (at least) twice, and that's the difference between two snippets. In the first one, value of `val` is increased by 2 *each time* `valueOf()` is called. It's easy to check, btw, with console.log():

```
return { 
  valueOf(){
    val = val + 2;
    console.log(`And now it's ${val}`);
    return val; 
  } 
}
```

... gives the following output:

> And now it's 0
>  
>   And now it's 2
>   inside

Second snippet, however, just gives result of `this.val + 2`, but never modifies `this.val`, and the result is always 0. Had it been written this way:

```
valueOf: function(){
  return this.val += 2;
}
```

... it would have worked completely the same as the first one.